# Adding conditions to <script src=..> in html using django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

html:

```
 <body>
    <script>
        var participants =[];
    </script>
    {% for player in playerList %}
        ...........
        {% empty %}
            <div style="text-align: center; color: Black; margin-bottom: 90%">
                <h2>empty</h2>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'event-management-system/js/index.js' %}"></script>

    </body>
```

I want want to stop the execution of `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'event-management-system/js/index.js' %}">` part when `participants =[]` is empty. How to do that?.

Comment: Please make sure your question is properly tagged. In this case you've added an unrelated `javascript` tag and you do not specify the templating language you are using. Doing these things will improve your chance of getting an answer you need.

Comment: I see I made a mistake, your question is actually related to JS, my apologies.

Comment: Is this using the django template language?

Comment: The matter is where the `participants` variable is coming from. If it is coming from the template it's possible to use the templating langue, otherwise using JavaScript is possible.

Comment: I am using django

Comment: @HasiniRanganaWeerasooriya when is the variable filled with content?

Comment: Contents are comming from the views.py file. If I can handle this by using partipants[] , it is also possible.

Comment: I want skip the loading of indes.js file when partipantv [] is empty

Comment: Yes, we understand your question. But in your example the `participants` is always empty. If it's value is coming from Django it should show so in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are using the django template language. If so, please tag as such. You can check the length of your list using `|length`. So do this

```
{% if playerList|length > 0 %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'event-management-system/js/index.js' %}">
{% endif %}
```

if you only want to include this `script` when `participants` is populated. Or you could simply do this

```
{% if playerList %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'event-management-system/js/index.js' %}">
{% endif %}
```

I believe, but the first one is more explicit and, in my opinion, easier to know what is happening.

Comment: In this case `participants` is defined in a script tag so I doubt it is available in the Django template. However if the source is also available there this would work.

Comment: @JonKoops Good point. I gather from the comments that `participants` is being supplied by `views.py`. If that's the case, then declaring it in javascript doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Indeed, the example for this question is not complete enough to gather a whole picture of where the data is actually coming from.

Comment: Well, for now I'll leave this answer in case I was able to fill in the blanks successfully. If made aware that more details invalidates this answer, I'll delete it.

Comment: Yes. It's working... Participants[] is created in html file. playerList is comming from the django,views.py file. Then It can be solved.

Comment: So this answer should be changed little bit... Thank you ...all of you

Comment: I'm guessing what you really wanted was `{% if playerList %}`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean JavaScript in browser then  you can do something.

```
<body>
<script>
    var participants =[];
</script>
{% for player in playerList %}
    ...........
    {% empty %}
        <div style="text-align: center; color: Black; margin-bottom: 90%">
            <h2>empty</h2>
        </div>
{% endfor %}

<script>
(function() {
   if(participants.length){
    document.write('<script src="{% static 'event-management-system/js/index.js' %}"><\/script>');
   }
})();
</script>

</body>
```